# Why do I get a messy csv when using the write.csv with the count function?

Tags: r

I created a test data frame, and ran a mutation on that data frame. I think this issue might occur because I used subset on the column from the count function. but I am not really sure.

```
df<- data.frame(treatment = rep(c("A","B","C"),times = 3),
                    numb = c(1:3,6:9,12,13))

df_test1 <- df %>%
 group_by(treatment) %>%
 summarise(mean= (mean(numb)), sum=(sum(numb))) %>% 
mutate(times = count(df, treatment)[2], thing = mean + sum) 

write.csv(df_test1, 'test.csv')
```

[image: A screenshot of the csv that code creates.]

Instead of 3 in the times column the value is c(3,3,3). Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `n()` to get the count instead of `count` as count expects a data.frame as input and returns a data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 group_by(treatment) %>%
 summarise(mean= mean(numb), sum=sum(numb), times = n()) %>%
 mutate(thing = mean + sum)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  treatment  mean   sum times thing
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 A          5.33    16     3  21.3
2 B          7       21     3  28  
3 C          8       24     3  32
```

---

If we check the `str`ucture of the output from OP's post, it becomes clear i.e. 'times' column is a `data.frame` as the subsetting was done as `[2]` instead of `[[2]]` to extract as a vector and `[2]` returns a data.frame with a single column.  For `data.frame`, even `[,2]` would work as `drop = TRUE` by default in `data.frame`, whereas it wouldn't work with `tibble` or `data.table`.  Safer is to use `[[`.

```
> str(df_test1)
tibble [3 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ treatment: chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"
 $ mean     : num [1:3] 5.33 7 8
 $ sum      : num [1:3] 16 21 24
 $ times    :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ n: int [1:3] 3 3 3
 $ thing    : num [1:3] 21.3 28 32
```

i.e. if we do `[[2]]`

```
df_test1 <- df %>%
 group_by(treatment) %>%
 summarise(mean= (mean(numb)), sum=(sum(numb))) %>% 
mutate(times = count(df, treatment)[[2]], thing = mean + sum)
```

check the structure again

```
> str(df_test1)
tibble [3 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ treatment: chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"
 $ mean     : num [1:3] 5.33 7 8
 $ sum      : num [1:3] 16 21 24
 $ times    : int [1:3] 3 3 3
 $ thing    : num [1:3] 21.3 28 32
```

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for all the info. So "[ ]" will subset an entirely separate dataframe from the originial, and "[[ ]]" subsetsa vector from the original.

Comment: @pabstack I would use `[[` as `[,2]` wouldn't work with `tibble` or `data.table`.  `[[2]]` works in all 3 cases